# What should I do when I've hit "start a new shell to examine the situation"

Tags: upgrade, configuration

I have selected "start a new shell to examine the situation" when upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 from the "Distribution Upgrade" tool.

The prompt popped up because the php.ini config file was going to be replaced, but the current one had been modified.

Now I'm in the installer shell (it hasn't opened a new one) and the installation stopped, it seems like if I have to do something, but I don't know what.

Distribution Upgrade is in the middle of the upgrade!

Should I press anything?

Comment: This saved my behind! I was expecting the shell to open in a new window. So when nothing happened, I thought the upgrade had frozen. I didn't realize the new shell opens inside the installer's terminal!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you encounter this while connected via SSH, you can open additional terminals and SSH into the machine, and open the old and new file in each terminal to take a better look at them.

Answer (score 20):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> re-enabled the prompt and allowed me to continue the installation.

Comment: That or `exit` to exit the shell and return to the installer.

Comment: Yes but the shell was the same as the upgrader is using, so closing the shell won't stop the installation?

Comment: It is a subshell, a shell-inside-a-shell;  `exit` would close only the subshell and return you to the original shell. It's exactly the same as Ctrl+D